# Setup service provider on unit testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a component the following:

**TS**

```
export class CashFlowSalariesComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

...

constructor(
    public apiService: ApiService,
    private modalService: NgbModal,
    private toastr: ToastrService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

Now I want to create a unit testing for it so I try

**.spec.ts**

```
describe('CashFlowSalariesComponent', () => {
    let component: CashFlowSalariesComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<CashFlowSalariesComponent>;
    let apiService: ApiService;


  
    beforeEach(async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
        imports: [
                            [RouterModule.forRoot([])],
                            RouterTestingModule,
                            FormsModule,
                            ReactiveFormsModule,
                            BrowserModule,
                            HttpClientTestingModule,
                        ],
        declarations: [ 
            CashFlowSalariesComponent,
        ],
        providers: [{provide: apiService}]

      })
      .compileComponents();
    }));
  
    beforeEach(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CashFlowSalariesComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();
    });
  
    it('should create', () => {
      expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
```

But this is throwing an error message:

> NullInjectorError:
> StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[CashFlowSalariesComponent ->
> ApiService]:    StaticInjectorError(Platform:
> core)[CashFlowSalariesComponent -> ApiService]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for ApiService!

As you can see, I tried to set the ApiService as a provider, but it did not work; what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

provide should receive a class, then you can either also declare the useClass or the useValue if you want to stub it.

```
providers: [{provide: ApiService, useValue: {methodExample: ()=>null}}]
```

If you don't want to mock the service, you could just add the class directly to the providers:

```
 providers: [ApiService]
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax to define dependency provider is:-
`[{ provide: apiService, useClass: ApiService }]`
And yes instead of useClass you can use - useExisting , useFactory, useValue properties. Please check on this page:- https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers

Comment: I tried but it returns: `NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule) NullInjectorError: No provider for ApiService!`